# Check if the parameter is null in the where clause from go sqlx

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

Given we have a record in the postgresql database like this:

```
name(varchar) nickname(nullable varchar)
John          null
```

We want to update that record based on the nullable nickname value like this:

```golang
type Contact struct {
  Name     string         `db:"name"`
  Nickname sql.NullString `db:"nickname"`
}

func update() {
  db, _ := sqlx.Connect("postgres", "connection_string")

  c := Contact{
    Name: "Doe",
  }
  q := "UPDATE contact SET name = :name WHERE :nickname = '' AND nickname is null OR nickname = :nickname"

  db.NamedExec(db.Rebind(q), c)
}
```

The query above will update a record only if the `c.Nickname` is a string value (assuming we have a matching record in the db). **How can I achieve this kind of logic: if `c.Nickname == nil` use `nickname is null` else use `nickname = c.Nickname`?**

Edit:

I tried this query `UPDATE contact SET name = :name WHERE CAST(:nickname as varchar) is null AND nickname is null OR nickname = :nickname`, it is working as I expected but still want to see if there is better alternatives

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to achieve? You want to set name for all the records where nickname is what?

Comment: This has nothing to do with sqlx or Go. You just need the proper SQL query.

Comment: I believe you're looking for the [`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#id-1.5.8.8.14.1) predicate.

Comment: sql.NullString has property Valid is true if String is not NULL.

https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString